# Avoid multiple page redirects REACT

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I have a simple website that I am building and I am currently trying to improve the SEO by using PageSpeed Insights. I score an 85 on mobile and one of the recommendations is that I avoid page redirects. I am using react-router-dom. In my app.js, I am using this

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // initializes Google Analytics
        this.initializeReactGA();
    };

    initializeReactGA = () => {
        ReactGA.initialize(process.env.REACT_APP_GA_TRACKING);
        ReactGA.pageview("/");
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollAnimation animateOnce={true} animateIn="fadeIn" className="App">
                <ContactHeader />
                <Header />
                <PortalContainer />
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Footer />
                <Copyright />
            </ScrollAnimation>
        );
    }
}
```

The redirects that are happening looks like this:

```
(Initial: http://URL.com/)
0 ms
https://URL.com
630 ms
https://www.URL.com
```

What can I do to avoid this from happening?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with react. You are forcing all non-www url requests to be redirected to www url on your web-server. If this is something you absolutely want then instead of checking pagespeed for non-www url check for www url.

Comment: @lakshman.pasala Where would I have done this? I don't remember purposely redirecting users to www url. I currently use netlify, is that where I would be doing it?

Comment: Which web server are you using?

Comment: @lakshman.pasala I was able to fix it within Netlify's settings. Thank you